# ActionMailer not sending mail in development Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am having some problem with sending email in my web-application. When I am running development the email is not sent even though it is showing as sent in the Console.

This is my settings in config/environments/development.rb

```
# Email
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: '587',
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: ENV["gmail_username"],
password:  ENV["gmail_password"],
authentication: :plain,
domain: 'gmail.com'
}
```

In my controller I am sending mail using this call:

```
 JobMailer.send_accept_job_mail(@app_user, @job.id).deliver
```

The mail is showing as "sent" in the Console, but it is not sent to the specified mail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [deliver!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Sending+mail) to send out the mail immediately.

Just update the code to

```
JobMailer.send_accept_job_mail(@app_user, @job.id).deliver!
```

-- edited to use `deliver!` method, per comments.

Comment: Hi. I originally had it as deliver_now, and it still didn't work. @matov

Comment: OK got it. Have you tried the bang method `deliver!`?

Comment: This actually worked in some way. I now got a Net::SMTPAuthenticationError. Which means that Google is blocking access to the application?

Comment: @ssandoy that means your credentials might be wrong. Check your ENV vars, make sure they have the correct details in them.

Comment: They look to be correct. I have declared them in /config/secrets.yml. Is it then correct to call ENV["name_of_variable"]? @matov

Comment: No, if you use secrets.yml, you need to access them through `Rails.application.secrets.gmail_username` (reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml). To use them through `ENV` you need to declare them in the environment through bash (i.e. `export gmail_username=USERNAME`) or use a gem like dotenv https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: Alright, changed that now. Still got the AuthenticationError, though... Even tried to give access to less secure apps in my gmail-account. @matov

Comment: Ok, the only last thing I can see that's different from an app I have is the port is a string in your settings, and not a number. Could you try to change it to `port: 587`?

Comment: It worked now! Greatly appreciated. Thanks :) Could you change your top-answer to deliver!, and I'll set it to answered. @matov.